# How do you correctly use php filters for validation?

Tags: php

I have recently discovered PHP Filter functions for sanitation and validation.

I have been wondering if im using them correctly and struggle to find much info about them, especially flags.

for example I have a sanitize function for email addresses.

```
function sanitize_email($var){
$var = trim($var);
$var = filter_var($var,FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
$var = filter_var($var,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$var = filter_var($var,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
return $var;
}
```

My questions are as follows?

Should i be using a combination of filters? or is FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL sufficient to secure the form field on its own?

Ive read that UNSAFE_RAW doesnt work unless you use a flag with it but i cant find a good example showing its use with a flag.

I also have a similar function for sanitizing a text field which looks like this...

```
function sanitize_text($var){
$var = trim($var);
$var = htmlspecialchars($var);
$var = filter_var($var,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$var = filter_var($var,FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
return $var;
}
```

Again I'm not sure I really need to do everything that I am with this function.

How do I improve on this function with regard to making the input secure?

Comment: "Secure" in what way, for what use?

Comment: See http://web.archive.org/web/20120512140932/http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html for a tutorial

Comment: Input filtering is not the way to go, filter/escape your variables on output.